# How to move bootstrap bottom navbar in a desired place?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bootstrap html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">  
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css">    

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

    <title></title>  
</head>
<body >  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">          
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">        
<img src="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a>      
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">    
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>  
</button>  
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">    
    <ul class="navbar-nav">      
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">خانه<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">درباره ما</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">          حساب کاربری        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="signup.php">ثبت نام</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">ورود</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
<div class="container py-5">


Lorem ipsum

</div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
<div class="container">

<a class="nav-link" href="privacy.php">سیاست حریم خصوصی</a>
<p>کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ است.</p>

</div>
  </nav>

  </body>
```

For short pages, footer is in middle of the screen, how to move it at the very bottom? I used fixed-bottom class, but this time for longer pages, the footer is over the last lines of the page and they are unreadable. How to fix it?

Comment: Check this out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
html {
  height: 100%!important;
}

body {
  -ms-flex-direction: column !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-light.bg-light {
  margin-top: auto !important;
}}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
      <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">    
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>  
</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">خانه<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">درباره ما</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">          حساب کاربری        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signup.php">ثبت نام</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">ورود</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container py-5">


    Lorem ipsum

  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="nav-link" href="privacy.php">سیاست حریم خصوصی</a>
      <p>کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ است.</p>

    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Comment: You are now adding to the post, it is now a new problem. Please open a new support request for this new issue.

Comment: Your css above causes lots of issues if viewing on mobile. This is not a new issue as I did not customize anything. please test your code on mobile too. @MistaPrime

Comment: I modified the CSS so that it only applies to desktop and not mobile.

Comment: Now footer on mobile for short pages are in middle instead of bottom. Would you please fix that for mobile too? @MistaPrime

Comment: The CSS I gave you does not apply on mobile. If you are seeing issue on mobile it is not because of the CSS I gave you, the issues were there before my CSS.

Comment: I know. I meant please give a media class for mobile too. @MistaPrime

Comment: Once you add more content the footer will also be at the bottom on mobile. If you want to force that you can add this CSS: `@media (max-width: 860px) {.container.py-5 {
    min-height: 600px;
}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position of the footer to `absolute` (i used inline style but it's not suggested...i did so just to point out clearly what i've done)

```
<footer style="display:block; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="nav-link" href="privacy.php">سیاست حریم خصوصی</a>
      <p>کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ است.</p>

    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```